# Action Link on custom facebook opengraph story isnt working

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have followed the facebook page on creating action links https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/action-links/
to the letter i have one object recipe
and 4 actions cook, create, save, improve

save is a used as a linked action to cook.
improve is used as a linked action to create

there are 4 stories, one for every action with the object.
cook recipe, create recipe, save recipe, improve recipe.

posting actions work fine and the action link is visible.

however when clicking it i get different errors depending on the action link
clicking save (on a cook story) - gives an error -

> Invalid Open Graph Action Link domain for URL ?signed_request=[base64]

clicking improve just returns status 500 from https://www.facebook.com/ajax/open_graph/actionlink

the interesting thing is both actions use the same https callback url.

has anyone managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into this in the future:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/action-links/ isn't very clear as to the Linked Action and Link Action Url. on the action you want to link you should choose the Linked Action, then open that actions advanced settings and enter a Link Action Url for the action itself.

After doing this everything worked like a charm.